# Composer installation of phpunit ends in root folder

Tags: vagrant, composer-php

I am installing PHPUNIT with COMPOSER on VAGRANT setup in this way:

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com 1231312312
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
....
composer global update
ln -s /home/vagrant/.config/composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

But the files where landing in /root/.composer/...
Can I change the path where global resources get installed too?

Comment: Global installation is always "only" global for the current user who is running Composer commands. Seems like your Vagrant setup is being run by "root", not by the "vagrant" user account.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is by design - 'global' in composer terms means *'not bound to a specific project'*, it is however still bound to the installing user to then be accessible in all projects. To make something system global additional action is required.

The folder is specified by the [`COMPOSER_HOME`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) environment variable, which you can override. As the documentation states:

> This is a hidden, global (per-user on the machine) directory that is shared between all projects.

It is explicitly intended to be a per-user folder, which you should keep in mind.